# facebook like widget strange behavior

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm using fb like in my page, after clicking on it the widget looks like it was clickec and the counter show 1as expected, but after refreshing the page the like widget returns to it's original state - not clicked and no like counter. The url seems to be grabbed correctly when I view it in the facebook debug tool, so it's not an og: meta issue and facebook does recognize this page correctly. I tried to check it with fb link_stat tool and the data seemed to be correct -

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+url%2C+normalized_url%2C+share_count%2C+like_count%2C+comment_count%2C+total_count%2C+commentsbox_count%2C+comments_fbid%2C+click_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url%3D%22http://107.21.224.181/recommendation/201%22&access_token={your_access_token}

but the like widget still show nothing - 
http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=190673301047799&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D6%23cb%3Df1ff56763%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252F107.21.224.181%252Ff328f6c124%26domain%3D107.21.224.181%26relation%3Dparent.parent&extended_social_context=false&href=http%3A%2F%2F107.21.224.181%2Frecommendation%2F201&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&node_type=link&sdk=joey&send=false&show_faces=false&width=90

Any clue or direction for this issue? We had those like buttons (fbml version) work nicely in the past but it seem not to work for more then a month now.

this is the like widget code -

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://107.21.224.181/recommendation/201" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Comment: please post the like code. I cannot find it on `http://107.21.224.181/recommendation/201`

Comment: Yan, I've updated my post so it contains the fb-like code (it's HTML5 not xfbml)

Comment: This piece of code looks OK. Are there JS errors on the page? How do you load the JS SDK?

Comment: No js errors, loading js sdk as follows - (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId={{fb_appId}}";
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was according to 2 issues:

1. Needed to add fb:app_id (or fb:admins) and og:site_nmae meta tags (according to this post - http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=210086019031867).
2. My inner page can be viewed only to user with session, BUT facebook need to have access to the specific url WITHOUT session. So a user without session will be now be redirected to external page which shows partial information.